# is there a better way to make something click-able other than using <a href="#">element</a>

Tags: jquery, html

I usually just use # to attach events to click-able elements without a url, but I was thinking about it and feel like it is a little hacky. Is there a better way to do this?

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/click_here.gif"/></a> 

$('a').click(function(event){
    alert('you clicked on the click button')
});
```

Comment: I think that this is the best way because at first, only `<a>`s where meant to be clickeable...

Comment: `<a />` means "hypertext Anchor". And `href` means "Hypertext REFerence". Neither of those is used correctly with `<a href="#">`.

Comment: Make something click-able? But every element is click-able by default (meaning: you can attach a click handler to any element on the page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite trick is to just attach the click handler to any old element, then use CSS to set `cursor: pointer` on it so it looks clickable. Bonus points if you add `:hover` and `:active` states to really tip the user off.

Example HTML:

```
<img src="images/click_here.gif" id="click-here-button" />
```

JS:

```
$("#click-here-button").click(function () {
    alert("You clicked on the click button.");
});
```

CSS:

```
#click-here-button
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: It is a good way, but some explorers (sigh old IE) will only add `:hover` CSS to `<a>`s

Comment: Yeah, if you have more specialized needs than Google and need to support IE6, then `<a>` is probably necessary. (Reference: http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/01/modern-browsers-for-modern-applications.html)

Comment: Why? There is only one `click_here.gif` button on the page. Presumably I don't want the same behavior for every clickable element. (I did edit my answer to use `click-here-button` as the id instead of `clickable` though, so maybe that will make the intent clearer.)

Comment: I do this all the time when making clickable things. An arrow cursor and a hover effect, and it's clickable!

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about that css attribute. very useful information.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jQuery I think anything can be clickable:

```
$('elementToClick').click(
    function(){
        alert('you clicked on a clickable thing');
    });
```

You could use the `hover()` method to simulate a hyperlink-look:

```
$('elementToClick').hover(
    function(){
       $(this).addClass('clickable'); /* or
       $(this).css('cursor','pointer'); */
    },
    function(){
       $(this).removeClass('clickable'); /* or
       $(this).css('cursor','auto'); */
    });

   $('elementToClick).click(
       function(){
           alert('you clicked the clickable thing');
           if (this.tagName == 'A') {
              return false;
           }
           });
```

Using CSS:

```
.clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wNT8m/)

Comment: @Šime well, that's true, yes. :)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the context. If the click action is supposed to link somewhere (even if you intercept that action), then that's what `<a />` means. Be happy with it. If you're triggering some other "non-navigation" functionality, I'd just put a click-handler on the `<img>` and set an appropriate cursor in CSS. Personal choice, to be honest.

Comment: Yeah, using `<a />`s and intercepting them does make a lot of sense, especially if you can link to an appropriate fallback non-JavaScript page (e.g. load manually instead of with Ajax).

Comment: I also like using stuff like `<a href="#my-dialog">` then intercepting that and using the value of the `href` attribute when I choose which dialog to show... doesn't help the user experience like my Ajax vs. manual loading example does, but it "feels right."

Comment: @Domenic: Yes and yes. I tend to switch between approaches depending on the project, use cases and how well I slept the previous night. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript:void(0); instead of "#"

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/click_here.gif"/></a>
```

This way you won't add the extra "#" in the URL.

Comment: But, the link will break when the user Ctrl+clicks, or right-clicks and chooses "open in new tab".

Comment: `javascript:` URLs are evil. "#" is good and proper; prevent anything from happening with `event.preventDefault()` in the `click` handler.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<input type="image" src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png">
```

Then just add an event handler and you're golden. :)